# not receiving any call back from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to alert anything inside the success ajax call, but it's not even alerting, I have checked my chrome insoector network and I am getting a 200 OK...

Here's my ajax call:#

```
$("#content").on("submit", "#add_qualification_form", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if(data.success == "false"){
                $.notify(data.error, "error");
            }else{
                $.notify(data.success, "success");
                $('#add_qualification').text("+ <?php echo System::translate("Add qualification"); ?>");
                $(".add_qualification_json").slideUp("slow");
                $("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>qualification/qualifications" + " #inner_main_content");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            }
        }
    });
        return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
});
```

And this is my response when directly viewing the page:

{"success":false,"error":"All inputs must be complete. Try again"}

But my alert is not working, nothing is working inside the `success: function`

The repsonse is a json, hence why I have set the dataType,

Comment: add these lines after `success` and check for any other `error` and log it. `error: function(jqXHR, responseText,status){console.log(jqXHR.responseText)}`

Comment: you're missing an error parameter after success: `error: function(data) {}` I'm not sure if its required but try an alert in there too

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao, thanks, man. That showed the error and my script is working again, for the error function, is that for debugging or should I be using it for production, too?

Comment: That is actually used to display any server side errors in a more precised text, basically to handle **error in ajax request**. So you can use it in production too and rather display a good message to user.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Guruprassad in the comments, I had to check the errors in the following function

```
error: function(jqXHR, responseText,status){
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
}
```

This helped check for server side errors rather than other errors.